# having an issue connecting with authentication with Firebase and Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to verify the connection with Google account and Email with no success.
I'm not sure if it is a problem with versions of Dependency even though I have checked it in the net for few times or it is something with my code that isn't correct

app.gradle

```
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.1.0'
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
```

gradle

```
   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
   classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'  // Google Services plugin
```

main.dart

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:authentication/ui/home.dart';
import 'package:authentication/ui/login.dart';
import 'package:authentication/ui/splash.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MainScreen(),
    );
  }
}


class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
      builder: (context,AsyncSnapshot<FirebaseUser> snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
          return SplashPage();
        if(!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data == null)
          return LoginPage();
        return LoginPage();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

firebase util

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';

class AuthProvider {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  Future<bool> signInWithEmail(String email, String password) async{
    try {
      AuthResult result = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email,password: password);
      FirebaseUser user = result.user;
      if(user != null)
        return true;
      else
        return false;
    } catch (e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  Future<void> logOut() async {
    try {
      await _auth.signOut();
    } catch (e) {
      print("error logging out");
    }
  }

  Future<bool> loginWithGoogle() async {
    try {
      GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
      GoogleSignInAccount account = await googleSignIn.signIn();
      if(account == null )
        return false;
      AuthResult res = await _auth.signInWithCredential(GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
        idToken: (await account.authentication).idToken,
        accessToken: (await account.authentication).accessToken,
      ));
      if(res.user == null)
        return false;
      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

splash

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SplashPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                CircularProgressIndicator(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                Text("Loading", style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                    fontSize: 18.0
                ),),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

login

```
import 'package:authentication/utils/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  TextEditingController _emailController;
  TextEditingController _passwordController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _emailController = TextEditingController(text: "");
    _passwordController = TextEditingController(text: "");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              const SizedBox(height: 100.0),
              Text("Login", style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 20.0
              ),),
              const SizedBox(height: 20.0),
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text("Login with Google"),
                onPressed: () async {
                  bool res = await AuthProvider().loginWithGoogle();
                  if(!res)
                    print("error logging in with google");
                },
              ),
              TextField(
                controller: _emailController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: "Enter email"
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 10.0),
              TextField(
                controller: _passwordController,
                obscureText: true,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: "Enter password"
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 10.0),
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text("Login"),
                onPressed: ()async {
                  if(_emailController.text.isEmpty || _passwordController.text.isEmpty) {
                    print("Email and password cannot be empty");
                    return;
                  }
                  bool res = await AuthProvider().signInWithEmail(_emailController.text, _passwordController.text);
                  if(!res) {
                    print("Login failed");
                  }
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

home

```
import 'package:authentication/utils/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Home Page'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("Home page"),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text("Log out"),
              onPressed: (){
               AuthProvider().logOut();
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Log while trying to connect via email and google account

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk...
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
D/EGL_emulation(12507): eglMakeCurrent: 0x9d385540: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9d383480)
D/EGL_emulation(12507): eglMakeCurrent: 0xa67b2940: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x86e94740)
I/zygote  (12507): Do partial code cache collection, code=29KB, data=21KB
I/zygote  (12507): After code cache collection, code=28KB, data=21KB
I/zygote  (12507): Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
D/EGL_emulation(12507): eglMakeCurrent: 0xa67b2940: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x86e94740)
I/flutter (12507): PlatformException(exception, Unknown, null)
I/flutter (12507): error logging in with google
D/EGL_emulation(12507): eglMakeCurrent: 0xa67b2940: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x86e94740)
I/zygote  (12507): Do partial code cache collection, code=61KB, data=42KB
I/zygote  (12507): After code cache collection, code=60KB, data=42KB
I/zygote  (12507): Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
I/BiChannelGoogleApi(12507): [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzao@d9d6493
D/FirebaseAuth(12507): Notifying id token listeners about user ( LnyMICjEyJNjtqKlCo5Qd8gAqva2 ).
```

Comment: share errors description

Comment: JFYI, Google auth with Firebase needs SHA fingerprint to be present in the firebase project app config. Check if that's the issue.

Comment: @Ganapat yes i know

Comment: @97loser just did